# Is it possible to write parquet files to local storage from h2o on hadoop?

Tags: r, hadoop, parquet, h2o

I'm working with h2o (latest version 3.26.0.10) on a Hadoop cluster. I've read in a parquet file from HDFS and have performed some manipulation on it, built a model, etc.

I've stored some important results in an `H2OFrame` that I wish to export to local storage, instead of HDFS. Is there a way to export this file as a parquet?

I tried using `h2o.exportFile`, documentation here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.exportFile.html but all the examples are for writing .csv. I tried using the a file path with `.parquet` as an extension and that didn't work. It wrote a file but I think it was basically a .csv as it was identical file size to the .csv.

example: `h2o.exportFile(iris_hf, path = "/path/on/h2o/server/filesystem/iris.parquet")`

On a related note, if I were to export my `H2OFrame` to HDFS instead of local storage, would it be possible to write that in parquet format? I could at least then move that to local storage.

Comment: You could try using Sparkling Water and convert it from an H2O frame to a Spark frame and use Spark to write parquet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I might give that a try. I was hoping for a more simplistic solution but maybe one doesn't exist.

Comment: *Update:* h2o supports exporting parquets as of 3.38.0.1: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Changes.md#zygmund-33801---9192022

Comment: @Hutch3232 Could you answer and accept yours? This question comes top at the google search and I just missed your comment here and came back..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h2o` added support for exporting parquet files as of [version 3.38.0.1](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Changes.md#zygmund-33801---9192022).

You need to set the `format` argument to be `"parquet"`. Note that `h2o.exportFile` will ignore the `parts` argument if you specify `"parquet"`. Instead, it chooses the number of parts based on the number of chunks of your data.

https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.exportFile.html

```r
h2o.exportFile(
  data = <your h2oFrame>,
  path = "/path/to/exported/parquet/dir",
  format = "parquet"
)
```